# CSS Breakpoints for Responsive Design

Tags: css, responsive-design

Twitter Boot strap uses these break points:

Large Display: 1200px
Default: 980px
Tablet: 768px
Mobile: 480px

A client said they are using 1280px for their Large Display breakpoint.

Is there an industry standard for these or are they just made up as we go right now?

Comment: They're probably made up.

Comment: AFAIK there is no such industry standard.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't an industry standard - really you should choose application / website specific breakpoints. Each UI and design will need different breakpoints. Making break points device agonistic is also recommend.

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/22/device-agnostic-approach-to-responsive-web-design/