# twitter bootstrap for high resolution mobile displays

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile

Twitter bootstrap is very awesome, but it is like hell when you want to give a good mobile site based on the collapse navbar part. How can I force twitter to use it and also to scale it in the right way. So it may look like facebook.

How it should look LG Optimus Black (480 x 800 pixel)

[image: How it should look]

How it looks like (Lumia 920 1280 x 768 pixel)

[image: How it looks like]

Comment: [Read about Responsive design](http://www.itworld.com/mobile-wireless/358564/designing-mobile-responsive-design-vs-mobilized-sites-vs-mobile-app)... I mean.. Facebook is not responsive

Comment: No its not. I know that bootstrap uses responsive design, but it sucks when u have a mobile site and get the desktop ui. I'll upload some pics.

Comment: Check this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16612475/2097224) out there are a good link... about breakpoints for responsive design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution

```
@-ms-viewport {
    width: auto!important;
}

@-webkit-viewport {
    width: device-width;
}

@-moz-viewport {
    width: device-width;
}

@-ms-viewport {
    width: device-width;
}

@-o-viewport {
    width: device-width;
}

@viewport {
    width: device-width;
}
```

Comment: This solution did not work for me - after adding this CSS I saw no changes when rendering on a mobile device.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding this to your `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

This works using Bootstrap 3.