# Bootstrap for high resolution displays

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Please before you call this as duplicate and vote down read it!
I know this solution ([twitter bootstrap for high resolution mobile displays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18796992/twitter-bootstrap-for-high-resolution-mobile-displays)) and I've used it but stil when I point to the site using Samsung S5 (high resolution mobile) it renders the tablet view instead of mobile.

Any other possible solutions beside using viewport initial-scale=1 or using the CSS mentioned in above question?

Amir

Comment: possible duplicate of [twitter bootstrap for high resolution mobile displays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18796992/twitter-bootstrap-for-high-resolution-mobile-displays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue!
It's very strange and interesting so I share for everyone who may have the same issue.

The solution with viewport works fine the issue really was how the mobile device was navigating to the site! I had a permanent redirect on my domain registrar (Godaddy) to redirect visitors to the actual deployment and that seemed to be the issue!

So here is the detail. My domain is aaaa.com and my code is deployed under bbbb.com/aaawebsitecontent
In aaaa.com domain registry I have a permanent redirect defined to redirect any request to aaaa.com to go to bbbb.com/aaawebsitecontent. If I point my mobiles browser to aaaa.com the viewport won't work! for some reason it still shows the high resolution desktop layout! If I point my mobile's browser to bbbb.com/aaaawebsitecontent then all works fine and system switches to the mobile layout!

I really can't explain why but regardless I know the issue's root cause!

Comment: saved my life ! this also occurs when your main site is running inside a frame (to hide context path). You either need to remove the frame, or add device width meta to frame head.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using [Bootstrap basic template](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template) for each website I've created and I haven't met with problems yet. I own Samsung Galaxy S4 which has the same resolution as S5 so there shouldn't be difference. You should try it too. If you are having problem with some site you have created it would be fine if you could attach some code so we can review it.

As you can see here, there is the same `<meta>` tag (I hope there is no difference between `scale=1` and `scale=1.0`) as in the question you have linked so yea, it is possibly duplicate question.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```